# Accessing a public property from with Repeater_ItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've got a user control which has a public property like so:

```
public string[] ImageIDArray {
    get;
    set;
}
```

Within my control I have a repeater, and inside that repeater I have a standard asp.net button. When the button is clicked I need to manipulate the ImageIDArray property. Im using the ItemCommand event handler.

The problem is when the ItemCommand handler runs the ImageIDArray is null. So, there's 2 questions here really.

1) At what point in the page lifecycle do properties get set (unless you programatically set them)
2) How do I get round this problem. Do I need to store the value in the viewstate?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 1):

The whole page life cycle is really stateless, apart from viewstate which gives a perception of state. The controls on the page get recreated every time you do a postback. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) MSDN article does a good job explaining it. The data that you loaded previously to the rendered controls are kept in viewstate (for the vs enabled controls) and are loaded back to them, unless user has changed them before posting back. If the user has changed them and you do a postback, those values are loaded in the `LoadPostBackData` event, which runs after the viewstate has been populated. 
I do not know where and when you are loading the data into your ImageIDArray but I'm assuming you are not loading it on every postback which is why the data is empty on your itemCommand event handler.

To answer your first question, just having a property does not do anything, it matters where you are setting the value to it. If you are assigning a value to the property in the ascx file, it stays with the control. Otherwise, you have to load it everytime.

Load the `ImageIdArray` on the `Page_Load` event of the user control. The page_Load event runs before your `ItemCommand` event is fired. If you don't want to load the `ImageArray` on every postback, you can consider storing that in the `session` or `viewstate`. Storing in the session means that the data is available for you for the session duration of the user. `ViewState` only lasts as long as you are on that page.

You can add data to the `ViewState` manually as `ViewState["ImageIdArray"] = ImageIdArray.` Or you can change your property as,

```
public string[] ImageIdArray

{

    get { return (string[])(ViewState["ImageIdArray"] ?? null); }

    set { ViewState["ImageIdArray"] = value; }

}
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513001943/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/TheBook/page1.asp) is an article that explains a little more about state management in asp.net.